# Who is that guy Sid referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

While on the set of Badge of Honor in *L.A. Confidential* (1997), Sid engages in conversation with Jack, all the while fiddling with a $50 bill between his fingers and thumb. Suddenly, Jack snatches it away.:

> Sid: Patchett's what I call twilight. He ain't queer and he ain't red.
> He cannot help me in my quest for prime "sinnuendo."

(Camera focuses on Reynolds and DA)

> Sid: As though Badge of Honor would touch **that guy** with a 10-foot
> pole... ...after he's been Hush-Hush cover boy twice in one year.

Who is that guy Sid referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That guy is [Matt Reynolds](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119488/characters/nm0048932?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t25), played by Simon Baker.

Sid is paying Matt to sleep with DA Loew so he can bust in and take pictures for Hush Hush, which will make Matt a cover boy twice.  The first time when Jack busted him for smoking pot after the movie premier.

In Sid's words to Jack...

> I'm getting him to f__ the D.A. for a hundred bucks.(winks) That's
> twice the fifty you got for wrecking his career.